# Some orders are duplicated in admin panel

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I don't know how to start because this is my first time posting something on a forum.

So the problem is some clients are ordering some products, but when I go to the admin panel to see their orders, I get surprised because their orders are duplicated. any ideas ? or solutions ?
I use the latest version of persatshop 1.7.8.7

I searched the entire internet for some solutions, but no results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First, it is needed to know if is a visualization problem, or really orders are duplicated in database. If each row in order list from backend has a different reference, it's sure they are duplicated in database. If there are repeated references, look into database (table orders) to make sure they are duplicated (or not). Once you have discern that, it's time to investigate more that line. But it will be difficult to help you at stackoverflow, this is not the kind of questions expected here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP, thx for help, it's not duplicated in database. it's only duplicated in the admin panel. My prestashop version was 1.7.6.8. I wasn't have this problem. but when I upgraded to 1.7.8.7 (latest version) this problem was occured. this is some screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/BcNr6Ie.png , https://i.imgur.com/wMPNBC0.png

Comment: click the gear at the top right of the order table and select "show sql query" , this will give you the complete query performed by Prestashop to retrieve the orders.

then connect to your DB with a client and paste  the query there , you should be able to troubleshoot more easily to figure out the source of the issue.

Comment: Ok, just a visualization problem, that's a good new. However, I didn't hear before about similar problem. Next question is: have you got any override or customization that can affect order list? I will try to help you, contact me at https://josecarlosphp.com/en/contact/

Comment: hey user3256843, I found it thx :) . The problem was, I created a module that search in the orders by the phone number, and the module query makes the visulalisation problem.  Now i need to start again and fix my module. and i don't know how :p